# Define list of a specific type (not object)

Tags: c#, .net, oop, list, object

I have:
- an interface : IMyType
- some classes implementing it : MyType1 , MyType2 , MyType3

How can I define a list of type IMyType?

```
var myList = new List<Type> {typeof (MyType1), typeof (MyType2)};
```

The above list does not force types to be IMyType type, and I can add any type to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<IMyType> lst = new List<IMyType>();
        lst.Add(new MyType1());
        lst.Add(new MyType2());
        lst.Add(new MyType3());

        foreach (var lstItem in lst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lstItem.GetType());
        }
    }
}
public interface IMyType { }
public class MyType1 : IMyType { }
public class MyType2 : IMyType { }
public class MyType3 : IMyType { }
```

If you want determine what's implementation class, you can use **obj.GetType()** or operator **obj is MyType1**

Comment: Thank's Peter.Actually I want a list of types, not a list of objects of that type

Comment: You must customize your list and catch exceptions on **Add** method and **Index** Property. Because you determine every type in C# inherited Type base

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
List<IMyType> list = new List<IMyType>();
```

Will do the trick you don't need any fancy stuff