# Use list of class types (or similar concept) to limit valid input

Tags: c#, .net

I have a number of classes inheriting from an abstract base class `Airplane`, examplified:

```
Airplane

-> F15
-> F16
-> Boeing747
```

Suppose I want to create another class, `AirplaneFactory` that takes a list (in the constructor) of possible airplanes it can build:

```
class AirplaneFactory {
    public AirplaneFactory(List<Type> airplaneTypes) {
        ....
    }
}
```

How do I limit those types to only `Airplane` and inherited classes? The end goal is to create different `AirplaneFactory` instances that can only "build" a specific subset of airplanes as specified.

I would like to limit it to the classes themselves without having to duplicate the work by using an `enum` or using String representations for classes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742276/how-do-i-check-if-a-type-is-a-subtype-or-the-type-of-an-object. I think that should have the info you need.

Comment: Although maybe not... I guess that wouldn't technically "limit" the types, it would just allow you to check the types passed in.

Comment: The same question is asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223073/define-list-of-a-specific-type-not-object, however the question has not been fully answered.

Comment: What do you think about a generic factory? `class AirplaneFactory<T> where T : Airplane
        {
            private readonly List<Type> _types = new List<Type>();
            public AirplaneFactory(List<T> airplaneTypes)
            {
                _types.AddRange(airplaneTypes.Select(o => o.GetType()));
            }
        }` So, when you try to create `AirplaneFactory<Airplane>` you can pass only list of `Airplane` and inherited classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible implementations:

```
 public class AirplaneFactory
 {
    private List<Type> _types = new List<Type>();

    //Implementation 1: Use an internal method to validate all items passed.
    public AirplaneFactory(IEnumerable<Type> airplaneTypes) 
    {
        AddTypes(airplaneTypes);
    }

    private void AddTypes(IEnumerable<Type> airplaneTypes)
    {
        var targetType = typeof(Airplane);            
        foreach (var item in airplaneTypes)
        {
            if (!item.IsSubclassOf(targetType))
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} does not derive from {1}", item.FullName, targetType.FullName));
            _types.Add(targetType);
        }
    }        

    //Implementation 2: Use a method to individually add the supported types
    public AirplaneFactory()
    {

    }

    //This method adds types one by one and validates the type
    public void AddType<T>() where T : Airplane
    {
        _types.Add(typeof(T));
    }               
}
```

(Notice the use of `IEnumerable<T>` instead of a concrete list)

Testing it:

```
  //Implementation 1: It will throw an error when FooClass is checked internally
  var factory = new AirplaneFactory(new[] 
  { 
       typeof(F15), 
       typeof(F16), 
       typeof(Boeing747), 
       typeof(FooClass) 
   });

  //Implementation 2:
  AirplaneFactory factory = new AirplaneFactory();
  factory.AddType<F15>();
  factory.AddType<F16>();
  factory.AddType<Boeing747>();
  //factory.AddType<FooClass>(); //This line would not compile.
```

**UPDATE:**

There is a third possible implementation if you abstract out the concept of an Airplane Type collection:

```
public class AirplaneTypeCollection : IEnumerable<Type>
{
    List<Type> _types = new List<Type>();
    public AirplaneTypeCollection()
    {

    }
    public void AddType<T>() where T: Airplane
    {
        _types.Add(typeof(T));
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _types.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<Type> IEnumerable<Type>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _types.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then your factory receives the class as an argument of the constructor:

```
public AirplaneFactory(AirplaneTypeCollection types)
{

}
```

Comment: My current solution is something like this, but the "TypeCollection" is a nice touch. I don't think there's a 100% neat way to do it, but this is probably the closts.

Answer (score 1):

For best compile time safety, the factory class itself can be generic. By constraining the types inside the generic definition, the program can always assume only the correct types are added (or created).

Although specifying types inside the constructor may speed up creating new subtypes, the checks can only be done in runtime, with the help of exceptions

By subclassing the planes themselves, the factory can be tuned to a specific subtype.
e.g. with the following setup:

```
public abstract class Airplane{}
public abstract class Fighter:Airplane{}

public class F15 : Fighter{}
public class F16 : Fighter{}
public class Boeing747 : Airplane{}

public class AirplaneFactory<T> where T : Airplane
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    public void Add(T plane) => list.Add(plane); //"Add" used as a general example, but something like "Create" can be used as well. If T itself should be creatable directly, the constraint 'where T: Airplane, new()' can be used
}
```

The following can be used, with the last line giving a compiler error:

```
var generalFact=new AirplaneFactory<Airplane>();
generalFact.Add(new F15()); //valid
generalFact.Add(new Boeing747()); //valid
var fighterFact = new AirplaneFactory<Fighter>();
fighterFact.Add(new F15()); //valid
fighterFact.Add(new Boeing747()); //Invalid!
```

---

Because you may want more subclasses then inheritance allows, you can use interfaces instead.

e.g.

```
public interface IAirplane{}
public interface IFighter:IAirplane{}
public interface IVertical:IAirplane{}
public abstract class Airplane:IAirplane{}

public class F15 : Airplane, IFighter{}
public class F16 : Airplane, IFighter{}
public class Boeing747 : Airplane{}
public class F14: Airplane,IFighter,IVertical{}

public class AirplaneFactory<T> where T : IAirplane
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    public void Add(T plane) => list.Add(plane);
}
```

And use the factories with the interfaces:

```
var generalFact=new AirplaneFactory<IAirplane>();
generalFact.Add(new F15()); //valid
generalFact.Add(new Boeing747()); //valid
var fighterFact = new AirplaneFactory<IFighter>();
fighterFact.Add(new F15()); //valid 
var verticalFact=new AirplaneFactory<IVertical>();
verticalFact.Add(new F14()); //valid
verticalFact.Add(new F15()); //Invalid
```

Of course, since it's a factory, Create functions would be expected, rather than 'Add' functions. But with a generic factory, there would always be the need of an extra specification. But that can be done with a method which reuses the factory constraint:

```
public class AirplaneFactory<T> where T : IAirplane
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    public void Add(T plane) => list.Add(plane);

    public PlaneType Create<PlaneType>()
        where PlaneType:class,T,new()
    {
        var res = new PlaneType();
        Add(res);
        return res;
    }
}
```

example

```
verticalFact.Create<F14>(); //valid
verticalFact.Create<F15>(); //Invalid!
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a list of types, you could use an AddAirplaneType-method to add a type to your factory.

```
public void AddAirplaneType<TAirplane>() where TAirplane : Airplane
{
    if(!airplaneTypes.Contains(typeof(TAirplane))
        airplaneTypes.Add(typeof(TAirplane));
}
```

This does not make it perfect, but manageable before compiling. Checking the type after giving it as an instance can only result in two things:

1. You have to skip the wrong types silently.
2. You have to throw an exception.

I don't like both, so I would go with an Add-Method, maybe multiple that even support multiple types at once.

```
AddAirplaneType<TAirplane1, TAirplane2, TAirplane3, TAiplane4>()
    where TAirplane1 : Airplane
    where TAirplane2 : Airplane
    where TAirplane3 : Airplane
    where TAirplane4 : Airplane
```

You get the concept.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it. Use generics for the factory:

```
public abstract class Airplane
{
}

public class F15 : Airplane
{
}
public class F16 : Airplane
{
}
public class B747 : Airplane
{
}

public class AirplaneFactory<T> where T : Airplane, new()
{
    public List<T> Inventory => new List<T>();

    public T Make() { return new T(); }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b747_factory = new AirplaneFactory<B747>();
        var a_b747 = b747_factory.Make();
        b747_factory.Inventory.Add(a_b747);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a class factory with a predefined set of "prototypes" from which to copy the properties then do the following:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b747_100 = new B747("100", false, 333400);
        var b747_300 = new B747("800", false, 439985);
        var b747_300sp = new B747("300sp", true, 287500);

        var factory = new AirplaneFactory<B747>(b747_100, b747_300, b747_300sp);

        var a_b747_300sp = factory.Make("300sp");
        // makes a cargo version of the B474
        var a_b747_800 = factory.Make("800");
        // makes a passenger version of the B474
        var a_b747_400 = factory.Make("400");
        // makes nothing. No prototype for 400 series

        var copy_of_a_b747_800 = a_b747_800.Clone();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Base class. Each airplane has a model moniker.
/// </summary>
public abstract class Airplane
{
    protected Airplane(string model, int engineCount)
    {
        this.Model=model;
        this.EngineCount=engineCount;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new airplane with properties from another (Copy constructor).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other"></param>
    protected Airplane(Airplane other)
    {
        this.Model=other.Model;
        this.EngineCount=other.EngineCount;
    }
    public string Model { get; }
    public int EngineCount { get; }
    public abstract float Mass { get; }
}

public class F16 : Airplane, ICloneable
{
    public F16(F16 prototype) : base(prototype)
    {
        this.Mass=prototype.Mass;
    }
    public F16(string model, float mass) : base(model, 1)
    {
        this.Mass=mass;
    }
    public override float Mass { get; }

    #region ICloneable Members
    public F16 Clone() { return new F16(this); }
    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return Clone();
    }   
    #endregion

}
public class B747 : Airplane, ICloneable
{
    public B747(string model, bool isCargo, float mass) : base(model, 4)
    {
        this.IsCargo=isCargo;
        this.Mass=mass;
    }
    public B747(B747 prototype) : base(prototype)
    {
        this.IsCargo=prototype.IsCargo;
        this.Mass=prototype.Mass;
    }
    public bool IsCargo { get; }
    public override float Mass { get; }

    #region ICloneable Members
    public B747 Clone() { return new B747(this); }
    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return Clone();
    }
    #endregion

}

public class AirplaneFactory<T> where T : Airplane
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use reflection to get the copy constructor for each type 'T'
    /// </summary>
    static ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(T) });
    /// <summary>
    /// Hold a table of monikers and planes of type T
    /// </summary>
    readonly IDictionary<string, T> models;
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a factor with some built in plane models
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="airplaneModels">The models that the factory can make</param>
    public AirplaneFactory(params T[] airplaneModels)
    {
        this.models=airplaneModels.ToDictionary((x) => x.Model);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Public API exposes a readonly table so users can't add whatever planes they want.
    /// </summary>
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, T> Models { get { return models as IReadOnlyDictionary<string, T>; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Add a plan for new planes. If the model already exists then do nothing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="prototype">The plane prototype to implement</param>
    /// <returns>True if the plans are added</returns>
    public bool ImplementNewPlans(T prototype)
    {
        if(!models.ContainsKey(prototype.Model))
        {
            models.Add(prototype.Model, prototype);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new plane from the prototype stored in 'Models'.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The model moniker</param>
    /// <returns>A new plane if the have a prototype, null otherwise</returns>
    public T Make(string model)
    {
        if(models.ContainsKey(model))
        {
            return ctor.Invoke(new object[] { models[model] }) as T;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

<sub>NOTE: I am using generic for the plane types, reflection for the constructor and a dictionary to hold allowed plane models</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a list of `Airplane` types to the `AirplaneFactory` constructor, pass it a list of `Func<Airplane>` (a delegate that creates planes).

```
sealed class AirplaneFactory
{
    public Airplane(IEnumerable<Func<Airplane>> airplane_types)
    {

    }
}
```

And use like so:

```
//Can only make F15 and Boeing747 instances:
new AirplaneFactory(List<Func<Airplane>> { () => new F15(), () => new Boeing747() });
```